# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2, y=3, z=4$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2, y=3, z=4$

$4=x^2 \rightarrow x=\pm2$

$\displaystyle V=\int_{-2}^2\int_0^3x^2dydx=\int_{-2}^2yx^2\Big |_0^3dx=2\int_0^23x^2dx=2\Big[x^3\Big|_0^2=16$

Please let me know if my solution is correct, thank you!

Comment: I think you should have specified that the solid is also bounded by $y=0$.  More importantly, the solid is above the surface $z=x^2$ but you have found the volume below this surface.  Drawing a diagram of the solid is not altogether easy but if you try it, I think it will help.

Comment: @David, the question does not specify whether y is bounded by $0$. In this case should I assume $y=-\infty$ on lower bound?

Comment: No, since it would not be bounded then.

Comment: Agree with @Fantini.  Are you sure the problem did not somewhere, implicitly or explicitly, specify $y\ge0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution would be correct if we assumed that $0\le y\le 3$. In fact, by doing a plot, we could see that the $xy-$ area that you took is as follows:

[image]